# Blocking Administrative Access to Authors and Subcribers?

Tags: admin, wp-admin, user-roles

I would like to turn off admin panel for authors and subscribers.

Is there any secure way to keep them away from admin panel?

Comment: Hi, welcome to WPSE! Please, take a look at the following apps so you can easily follow your questions and answers in all StackExchange sites: http://stackapps.com :)

Answer (score 1):

Create a [functionality plugin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/72160/where-do-i-put-the-code-snippets-i-found-here-or-somewhere-else-on-the-web) and use this if you want to completely block the access to the Admin panel:

```
/**
 * Hide the admin bar in the front end 
 */
add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false');

/**
 * Redirects Authors and Subscribers to the site front page using: get_home_url()
 */
add_action('admin_init','block_users_wpse_53675');

function block_users_wpse_53675()
{
    if( !current_user_can( 'delete_pages' ) ) // blocks authors, contributors and subscribers
    {   
        wp_redirect( get_home_url(), 301 ); 
        exit;
    }
}
```

---

Or use this other one if you want the users to have access only to their profile page:

```
/**
 * Redirect Authors and Subscribers to the site front page
 * Except if viewing the Profile page
 */
add_action('admin_init','block_users_wpse_53675');

function block_users_wpse_53675()
{
    global $pagenow;
    if( 'profile.php' == $pagenow ) 
        return;

    if( !current_user_can('delete_pages') ) 
    {   
        wp_redirect( get_home_url(), 301 ); 
        exit;
    }
}

/**
 * Hide all menus from the Admin panel
 * Except the profile item
 */
add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_admin_menus_wpse_53675', 999);

function remove_admin_menus_wpse_53675() 
{
    if( !current_user_can('delete_pages') ) 
    {
        remove_menu_page('index.php');
        remove_menu_page('edit.php');
        remove_menu_page('upload.php');
        remove_menu_page('link-manager.php');
        remove_menu_page('edit.php?post_type=page');
        remove_menu_page('edit-comments.php');
        remove_menu_page('tools.php');
    }
}
```

---

#### Plugins of interest to manipulate Roles and Capabilities

- [Members](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members/)
- [User Role Editor](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/user-role-editor/)
- [Role Scoper](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/role-scoper/)
- [S2Member](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/s2member/)